# Use same variable name in htaccess for rewriting PHP page

Tags: .htaccess, url, rewriting

I have two pages `index.php` and `page_detail.php`, I'm using the following code in `.htaccess` for rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /page_detail.php?cat=$1&title=$2&pageId=$3&id=$4 [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /page_detail.php?countryname=$1&country=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

URL rewriting is working good when I am on the index.php page. When as I move to `detail_page.php` then every href shows after page URL the following:

First page URL (good working): `example.com/country/586/3.html`

Trouble in: `example.com/country/586/country/586/3.html`

HTML link code:

```
<a href="<?=country_name($con,$row['country'])?>/<?=$row['country']?>/<?=$row['id']‌​?>.html">
```

Comment: I think this also has to do with the paths in HTML/PHP code, can you please post the code where the href links are?

Comment: Yes sure..<a href="<?=country_name($con,$row['country'])?>/<?=$row['country']?>/<?=$row['id']?>.html">

Comment: actually, it removed last parameter value and consider it as a baseurl and throw url

Comment: Better to use absolute URLs in your links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to make the links look like this:

```
<a href="/<?=country_name($con,$row['country'])?>/<?=$row['country']?>/<?=$row['id']‌​?>.html">
```

(note the leading `/`)

or add this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: One think more, how can add many rewrite urls which has same length varibles like. RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /page_detail.php?cat=$1&catId=$2&id=$3 [L] and RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /page_detail.php?catname=$1&productId=$2&id=$3 [L]